# CUDA understanding clock rate

Tags: cuda

I'm querying the device capabilities with CUDA and I got the following information:

```
Device 0: Quadro K5000
  Total Memory: 4294639616 bytes
  Clock Rate: 705500 kilohertz
  Max. Threads per Block: 1024
  SM Count: 8
  Execution Timeout Enabled: 1
  Max. HW Texture Count: 128
  TCC driver enabled: 0
  CUDA Device Ordinal: 0
```

What does it mean the device "clock rate" field? Is it the clock for one SP (or cuda core) or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the GPU clock, just like your CPU has a clock. Clock rate is a standard electrical engineering term: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clock_rate

705500kHz = 705.5MHz

Your computer's CPU also has a clock rate. When you buy a computer, the CPU's clock rate usually is advertised and for a long time, performance was directly proportional to the clock rate.

Roughly speaking the clock rate determines how many processing steps given a certain time a processor performs. However processing steps doesn't equal instructions.

Comment: how does this relate to the SPs?

Comment: All the cuda cores are driven by the same clock. Which in turn means, all the SPs are driven by the same clock. To be honest, the clock rate is no parameter that is of any use in optimizing your programs. It just tells you, at which rate the processor does its thing. If your kernel takes 1000 clocks to execute, it will take 1000 clocks and that's it.